# What is the distribution of nen type users?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

There are [6 types of nen](http://hxh.wikia.com/wiki/Nen#Types_of_Nen):

- Conjuration
- Emitter
- Enhancement
- Manipulation
- Transmutation
- Specialization

I'm not sure if all types occur equally, or if all types except specialist occur equally and specialist is less common, or if all of them occur at different rates.

I have attempted to research this question for an RPG I intend to run, however I have not found any information on this topic.

What is the distribution of nen type users? Information from any official source is welcome including all of the anime & manga.

Comment: I mean in the world are there more (enhances,Transmuters,Conjurers,...)

Comment: Hunter x Hunter RPG. Is it like a D&D rpg?.... I.... I want that... gimme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is like DNA, you only know that specialists are the rarest and least common,as they explain in the episode "Desire x and x Promise". But the other categories are random. It is assumed that the enhancers are the most common, but there is nothing that says this with real certainty.

Answer (score 0):

It has not been stated in the anime or manga, but something that might help has been stated in the manga. The difference in aura type according to personality:

- Reinforcement: pure and simple
- Transformation: liars and unstable
- Conjuration: nervous
- Emission: impatient, emotionally disturbed
- manipulation: reasoners, advance at their own pace
- specialization: individualistic and charismatic

Comment: This was stated in the anime by Hisoka